# what's the best subscription-based billing system for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, billing

I'm looking for alternatives to Chargify for a billing system that can be integrated with Rails 3, preferably one that is subscription-based. I have looked into Chargify and am wondering if there are other comparable systems with easy-to-follow API available?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm going to test all three to see which one suits my app best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Recurly. You can see the API documentation at docs.recurly.com.

Answer (score 0):

How about a [RailsKit](http://railskits.com/recurring_billing/) (it's SaaS)

Answer (score 0):

u can try [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), no monthly fees, just per charge